# In NiFi FetchS3Object is it possible to read all objects with a specific prefix?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I am using FetchS3Object of NiFi to read from an S3 bucket. On Settings you can specify the key of the object to retrive. Is it possible to retrive all objects providing the prefix instead of the key?

This is a sample of my structure:

```
bucket-name
|--folder1
|----file1
|----file2
|--folder2
|----file1
|----file2
```

For example I want read all files inside `folder1`.Using S3 SDK I list all object wirh prefix `folder1` and then fetch any single object with the specific prefix.

One possible solution that come to my mind is to develop a cusom Processor to do what I want.

I cant't use ListS3 processor because I need to trigger the fetch from S3 when I receive an event (Flow FIle) from outside. List processor wait events from S3

Comment: If event has the s3 path of object you want to fetch, just use it

Comment: I don't have the full path of single object and I don't know how many file are in the "folder". I need to retrive all object with a specific prefix (aka "folder")

Comment: you can configure your bucket to send you SQS or SNS notifications every time new file added to the bucket. These messages will have full S3 path and you can get these messages with NiFi. But, seems you have custom logic with events you get.

Comment: The files are already on the bucket so I can't use this mecanism. I need to read data when I receive a custom event (internal of my system).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to have aws cli installed on NiFi nodes and then you can use ExecuteProcesss script that will run command like this:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket $BUCKET --prefix $PREFIX_IF_YOU_HAVE_IT --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '$VALUE_FROM_PREVIOS_PROCESSOR')]" | jq ".[0] .Key"
```

I recommend to use prefix to reduce time required to scan your bucket. jq is used here to extract json value with prefix for found file. You may need to change the command a little, but it will give you a direction.

Comment: Instead of using an external system, I will implement a custom processor